# how to query for blank field in mongodo

Tags: mongodb

I have the following field in a mongoDB document:

```
"category": {
 "0": {
   "id": "52e7fae8763f4aef308b465b",
   "name": "Mortgage Professionals",
   "name_singular": "Mortgage Professional",
   "group": "Home" 
} 
},
```

The `category` can have any number of subdocuments, 0 to n.  Some of them are blank.  How can I query for all blank subcategories that are blank; i.e. where `id` is not there or blank?

Comment: If `category` is a subdocument with numeric subdocs as you show, you should consider changing your schema so that `category` is an array of subdocs instead. Otherwise you'd have to hack this with a painfully slow `$where` query.

Comment: What does "Some of them are blank" mean?    If I have only 3 subdocs, what would be the reason to have, say, category.0 be unset but category.1 be set?